# CDF of $Y$ given the CDF of $X$ where $X>Y$

Tags: probability

Say, we have two positive random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X > Y$. Let $F_X$ be the CDF of X. Then, how can I find the CDF of $Y$? 
Please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't enough information to find the CDF of $Y$.

Comment: $F_Y(z) \gt F_X(z)\, \forall z $

Comment: @Henry I think you can only conclude $F_Y(z) \ge F_Y (z) \forall z$.  (Equality is needed in this example: $Y = \{1, 10\}$ with equal prob, and $X = Y+1$, then $F_X(4) = F_Y(4) = 1/2$.)

Comment: @antkam - that is a good example

Comment: Thank you very much all :)